# Vk api python 2.7 py2exe

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, python-2.x

Господа , подключил `vk api` , в среде все работает и посты благополучно уходят на стену -

```
import vk_api 
import sys 
import requests 

def vk_auth(login, password):
    vk = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)
    try: 
        vk.auth() # Авторизируемся 
    except vk_api.AuthError() as error_msg: 
        print(error_msg) # В случае ошибки выведем сообщение 
        sys.exit()
    return vk 

login=raw_input("login: ") 
password=raw_input("password: ") 

vk=vk_auth(login, password) 

message=raw_input("post: ") 

rs = vk.method('wall.post', { 
               'owner_id':-xxx, 
               'message': message,
               'from_group' :1 
               })
```

Когда собираю приложение через `py2exe` - получаю ошибку:

```
requests.exceptions.ssl error errno 2 no such file or directory
```

вот сетап

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=[{"script":"vk.py"}],
      options={"py2exe": { "includes":["vk_api","sys","requests","os"]} 
})
```

Подскажите, как решить, плиз?

Comment: получаете ли вы ошибку с `import requests; print(requests.get('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661155').headers)` скриптом?

Comment: в спайдере все супе получаю ответ -{'Content-Length': '35640', 'Via': '1.1 varnish', 'X-Cache': 'MISS', 'X-Request-Guid': 'ba3c1661-5e12-4...Если собираю приложение получаю ошибку в консоли -errno 22] no such file or directory

Comment: это значит, что проблема c requests, а не с vk не относится. Связанный вопрос: [Py2Exe No such File or Directory Error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32289972/4279)

Comment: А вы уверены что там вообще нужен requests попробуйте убрать импорт, вроде в vk_api уже все есть.

Comment: Убрал request  та же ошибка при запуске приложения